# Angular2 Animation Transitions only firing for some events

Tags: angular, animation

First off, [here is a plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/js0Ch8Ux4GIBlCel8PLQ?p=preview)

This is forked from [this page transition animation example](https://embed.plnkr.co/PcRpcGK2duGw0HdaGaF5/?show=preview)

basically, I need to set custom states because I have different animations for different actions in the site (first load vs page transition in-app, for example). The component classes have the following code: (`home` and `about` are pretty much the same)

```
import { Component, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationEnd, NavigationStart } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { routerTransition } from './router.animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  template: `<h1 [@routerTransition]="navState">Home</h1>`,
  animations: [routerTransition()]
})
export class Home implements OnDestroy{

  navState: string = 'start';
  subscribed: Subscription;
  constructor (private router: Router) {

    this.subscribed = router.events.subscribe((routerEvent) => { 

      console.log('routerEvent', routerEvent);

      if (routerEvent instanceof NavigationStart) {
        this.navState = 'start';
      }
      if (routerEvent instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        this.navState = 'end';
      }
    });
  }

  onDestroy () {

    if (this.subscribed) {
      this.subscribed.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
}
```

and the animation:

```
import {trigger, state, animate, style, transition} from '@angular/core';

export function routerTransition() {
  return slideToRight();
}

function slideToRight() {
  return trigger('routerTransition', [
    state('start', style({position:'fixed', width:'100%'}) ),
    state('end', style({position:'fixed', width:'100%'}) ),
    transition('start => end', [
      style({transform: 'translateX(-100%)'}),
      animate('0.5s ease-in-out', style({transform: 'translateX(0%)'}))
    ]),
    transition('end => start', [
      style({transform: 'translateX(0%)'}),
      animate('0.5s ease-in-out', style({transform: 'translateX(100%)'}))
    ])
  ]);
}
```

as you can see in the plunkr, the `'start => end'` transition is fired and works properly. However, the reverse, `'end => start'` is never fired.

What's going on here?

Thanks so much for any help.

Comment: You want to achieve with the same setup or I can change it a bit?

Comment: @micronyks as long as the requirements I proposed in the question are met, you can change the setup to your liking.

Answer (score 1):

I have a working fork of your [Plunkr here](https://plnkr.co/edit/6VxHlH?p=preview). I would recommend following [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9845).

I've basically added:

```
host: {
  '[@routerTransition]': 'true',
},
```

to all your components: `home.component.ts` and `about.component.ts`). In addition, changed your `slideToRight()` function to use the states `void` and wildcard `*`.

Comment: thank you for your response, however, this does not solve my problem. As stated in my question, I need to use custom animation states, and cannot use `*` and `void` to trigger the animations (for example, I do not want the page transition animation firing upon first load)